# How to handle QDialogButtonBox RestoreDefaults button

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

In Qt Designer I created a dialog box that has a `QDialogButtonBox` with OK, Cancel, and "Restore Defaults" buttons in it. It took a while, but I figured out how to setup the signals/slots in my implementation file with:

```
QPushButton* resetButton = m_ui.buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::RestoreDefaults);
connect(resetButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(resetDefaultsPressed()));
```

My question is this: Is there a way to setup the signals/slots in QtDesigner like you can with the OK and Cancel buttons? I haven't been able to find a signal called `RestoreDefaults` or similar... The method I have works, but it would be nice if all the signal/slot setup was together in the `.h` file that uic generates.

Answer (score 1):

Qt Designer can only handle the signals declared in the class.

But you can write a new class derived from `QDialogButtonBox`, use the signal `clicked` to receive which button role has been triggered, and emit new signals.

Then you can either promote your `QDialogButtonBox` to that new class in the designer and you'll have to manually add the signals for each ui file (with a left-click on your promoted widget then "Change signal/slots..."), or write a designer plugin to have your custom class(es) appear in the designer widget list (see [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8138846/894321) for details).

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by adding

```
<connection>
 <sender>buttonBox</sender>
 <signal>clicked(button)</signal>
 <receiver>OptionsWindow</receiver>
 <slot>clicked(button)</slot>
</connection>
```

to my `OptionsWindow.ui` `<connections>` section, and then in code it is:

```
void OptionsWindow::clicked(QAbstractButton* button)
{
    if (mUi->buttonBox->buttonRole(button) == QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole::ResetRole)
    {
        mOptionsData = OptionsData();
        mSavedOptionsData = mOptionsData;
        updateUi();
    }
}
```

as a slot.